# Authorize.net Payment Gateway Integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am trying to integrate Authorize.net payment  api in my app.There is no libraries for iphone in the website http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/samplecode.I am searching some other website and test login authentication like this.

```
NSString *soapMessage=[NSString stringWithFormat:
                       @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                       "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                       "<soap:Body>\n"
                       "<FunctionName xmlns=\"https://apitest.authorize.net/soap/v1/\">\n"
                       "<merchantAuthentication>\n"
                       "<name>%@</name>\n"
                       "<transactionKey>%@</transactionKey>\n"
                       "</merchantAuthentication>\n"
                       "</FunctionName>\n"
                       "</soap:Body>\n"
                       "</soap:Envelope>\n"
                ,@"7uiT3456",@"6TyperT234"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll"];
```

I get an output always

#### The following errors have occurred.

(13) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.

I don't know is this the correct way? if any other better way to integrate authorize.net api please guides me.

Comment: what website were you using for tips on how to implement Authorize.net? I am not even sure where I should start.

Comment: Which Env you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a developer account? If you don't, and you use the test server like you are, then you will get this error. Sign up for a [developer account](https://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/) and use those credentials for testing. That should solve your problem.

**Update 2011-11-23**

Authorize.net now offers an [iOS SDK](http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/)

Comment: If you are using a developer account and the test server and are getting this error then you have either an incorrect login or transaction. That's the only other way to get this error.

Comment: @ John Conde test account is for developer.I will signup for a developer account and logging in to test.authorize.net.it's working perfect...